# Dosbox, Xvesa, как отпозиционировать

Tags: linux, sdl

Привет,
юзаю `Tiny Core`, ядро, несколько расширений.

Так работаю в консоли, но для `dosbox` пришлось развести иксы. Запускаю `Xvesa` без оконного менеджера, без ничего вообще, только сервер и все. Там я запускаю `dosbox`. Но вот проблема, аргумент - `geometry` с ним не работает, а я хочу отпозиционировать коробочку по центру экрана, если она не запущена с аргументом `fullscreen=true`.

**Возможно ли это без использования оконного менеджера (нап . `hackedbox`)?**

Comment: не уверен, что `xdotool` сможет работать без *wm*, но проверьте что-нибудь вроде: `xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 10 10` (сдвигает текущее активное окно на позицию 10x10 от левого верхнего края экрана).

Comment: Придется собрать эту утилиту самостоятельно, чуть позже попробую и напишу здесь о результатах. Спасибо.

Comment: ну, раз «требуется собирать», так собирайте `xephyr`. в прошлом году, вроде бы, его наконец-то научили понимать параметр `-geometry`. это встраиваемый xserver, который можно запустить как окно в другом. а если бы `dosbox`-у не требовался opengl, то подошёл бы и более скромный в потребностях `xnest` — он-то `-geometry` понимает с рождения.

Comment: Что ж... если это самое легковесное и реалистичное решение, то добавлю себе в папочку расширений Xephyr весом в целых 12 мегабайт :)
Абыдна, конечно, что Xvesa весит в разы меньше (вроде как), но хозяин барин - хочется-колется. Спасибо за решение. Годится.

Comment: Как вариант еще подсказывали считерить и использовать какой-нибудь ОЧЕНЬ маленький WM, но я пока не нашел ни одного, в котором не было бы (по крайней мере изначально) ни оформлений окон, ни границ, ни элементов управления, ни менюшек по нажатию мыши... И который позволял бы просто запустить какую-то команду с использованием себя и отпозиционировать окно-регион на экране. Ни TWM, ни FLWM не подошли по этим критериям, хотя рекомендовали именно их.

Comment: а ещё можно добавить в `dosbox` стандартную опцию `-geometry`. и людям польза, и себе удобство.

Comment: кстати, а перетаскивать окно мышкой с нажатой клавишей *alt* не получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перечислю несколько из теоретически возможных вариантов позиционирования окна программы, не умеющей делать это самостоятельно, без привлечения *window-manager-а* (на примере *dosbox-а*):

1. если `dosbox` собран и запущен с использованием `sdl`, воспользоваться переменной окружения из «хозяйства» `sdl`: `SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS=10,20 dosbox` запустит окно `dosbox` с координатами `10` по горизонтали и `20` по вертикали (а с переменной `SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED=1` окно будет по центру экрана);
2. дописать поддержку опции `-geometry WxH+X+Y` в *dosbox-е*;
3. воспользоваться программой `Xnest` (встраиваемый *xserver*), знающей, что такое `WxH+X+Y`, но, к сожалению, не поддерживающей «ускорение графики», которое требуется *dosbox-у*;
4. воспользоваться программой `Xephyr` (почти то же самое, что и `Xnest`, но значительно «жирнее»), поддерживающей «ускорение», и уже [почти год понимающей](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/commit/hw/kdrive/ephyr?id=84b02469ef97e6f85d074d220a517d752180045f) опцию `-screen WxH+X+Y`;
5. воспользоваться программой `xdotool` примерно так: `xdotool getactivewindow windowmove X Y`;
6. перетащить окно мышкой с нажатой клавишей <kbd>alt</kbd>.

Comment: 1. Вариант интересный, но насколько заморочный?.. Хотя, вполне реальный.
4. По-моему, она с Xvesa не дружит... Во всяком случае помню, что пробовал.
5. Если запустить только Xvesa, то таскать регионы приложений таким образом не получается :( Уже пробовал. К тому же, хочется, чтобы это было автоматизировано. Запускаешь досбокс -- запускается Х, переключается на него, а там в центре уже открыт досбокс, а на фоне обоина красивая. Так что буду думать над вариантами 1, 3.

Comment: Сложность не в том, чтобы дописать, а в том, чтобы локализовать место, где решается, как и куда отрисовать окно.

Comment: гуглёж по поводу «sdl window position» подсказал переменную окружения `SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS`.  дополнил ответ.

Comment: Я не обратил внимания на тот факт, что эмулятор использует sdl... Протупил

Comment: если ответ решил проблему, отметьте его, пожалуйста, «принятым» («галочка» слева от ответа).

Comment: Вариант с переменными окружения не работает. Ну, в принципе, векторы обозначены, можно сказать, что решен. Сейчас, если в течение часа не заработает полностью как надо, отмечу. Если заработает - отмечу раньше с дополнительным комментарием, как все круто))

Comment: может быть, у вас не sdl используется. в сборке из debian-овского репозитория – позиция меняется.

Comment: Это не может зависеть от конкретной реализации Х-сервера? У вас Xorg, у меня Xvesa, например. Потому что при запуске dosbox он иногда ругается, что не может проинициализировать SDL, тогда нужно запустить его с sudo, чтоб он смог. То есть явно он все-таки SDL использует..

Comment: *запустить его с sudo*. кхм, мда. а попытаться определить, на доступ к чему программе прав не хватает, не пробовали? `strace`-ом каким-нибудь…

Comment: Я с этим делом долбаюсь всего два дня, не растекаясь мыслью по древу. Решил бы одну задачу (например, регион стал бы позиционироваться) - мог бы задуматься о том, зачем мне все время запускать программу с правами суперпользователя. Хотя по большому счету: у меня не сервер, не киоск обслуживания, а обычный десктоп. Ну, за исключением того, что десктопа там нет, главное, что домашний. Чистоплотность, конечно, хороша везде, но бояться-то мне здесь нечего.
А strace не хочет работать, вместо запуска (и по гуглу, и по наитию) все время справку показывает. Может, придется и отложить.

Comment: кстати, по поводу переменной: вы уверены, что она попадает в окружение программы? посмотреть можно так: `/proc/номер-процесса-dosbox/environ | xargs -0n1 echo`

Comment: Вот про чат система ругается, а сама же из-за репутации перенести и не позволяет. Пускай не ругается тогда, раз мало.
Да, переменная не попадает в окружение. По крайней мере, текстовый файл environ в папке с пидом досбокса ее не содержит.
Я задаю ее в файле .xsession, где у меня и досбокс стартует. Наверное, что-то не так делаю. Запускаю startx, он кушает .xsession, запускает Xvesa, после старта стартует dosbox, в общем, в этом плане все как надо. Да и других подходящих конфигурационных файлов этого Х-сервера я не нашел.

Comment: добавьте переменную прямо при вызове *dosbox-а* — это, во-первых, надёжнее, во-вторых, по-моему, правильнее, чем определять её глобально в `.xsession`.

Comment: по поводу чата: как наберёте [двадцать «очков»](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) — право будет. а то, что предлагает, конечно, неверно. сейчас баг-репорт напишу на [meta].

Comment: Готово! Я просто никогда раньше так не делал, поэтому не понял, что именно как сказано: SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS=10,20 dosbox так и надо делать. И разделил на две строки в .xsession.
Только использовал другую переменную: SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED. В этом случае она еще удобней. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ubuzqysz0our37y/success.png

Comment: поздравляю! дополнил ответ информацией про `SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED=1`